# SciDraw doesnt plot full function over desired domain?

Tags: plotting, scidraw

Let me remark that I'm relatively new to using SciDraw, but I have read through the tutorial.  Currently I'm using SciDraw v0.7 in Mathematica 10.2.  I find that there is very strange behavior when defining a Plot in the FigGraphics wrapper over a range different from what XPlotRange is specified to be.  For example, I want to plot

$
f(x) = -\frac{(1-x) \left(2 x^3+4 x^2+6 x+3\right)}{2 \left(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1\right)}
$
over $x \in [1,10]$

I define the SciDraw canvas as,

```
Figure[
 FigurePanel[
  {
   FigGraphics[Plot[f[x], {x, 1, 10}]];
   },
  XPlotRange -> {1, 10},
  YPlotRange -> {0, 1}
  ],
 CanvasSize -> {5, 3.5}
 ]
```

[image]

The canvas ranges are correct but the plot appears to be cut off at $x=2$.  What is even more strange is if I change the range over x in the Plot command to $\{x,0,5\}$ I get,

[image]

Indeed, $f(x) = 0$ at $x=1$ and if I just run the regular mathematica command,

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 1, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

I get a full correct plot.  Anyone else experience this or know of a fix?  Is the input correct?

Comment: Well, just include the `PlotRange -> All` in `Plot` even when using it in `FigGraphics`.  Within `Plot`, that option controls *what gets plotted*, not what gets shown.

Answer (score 3):

`PlotRange` does something different in `Plot` vs `Show`/SciDraw.

In `Plot`, it controls which part of the curve should be generated.

In `Show`, it controls the range of the plot frame.  Only objects within the plot frame are visible.

You are (perhaps implicitly) assuming that `Plot` generates the full curve, even those parts which fall outside of the plot range.  Thus increasing the plot range *after* the plot has been created should reveal more of the curve.  This is not the case.  The sections of the curve outside of the plot range will not even be generated by `Plot`.

Example:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Solution: Use `PlotRange -> All` within `Plot`.  This setting is completely independent of the `YPlotRange` setting of SciDraw. Use both simultaneously.